# Managing resources in a sitelet

Tags: javascript, css, f#, websharper

I'm beginning my trek in learning WebSharper, and I'm finding managing resources (e.g. css and javascript files) a bit confusing.

The [documentation](http://websharper.com/docs/resources) on this gives an example resource declaration

```ml
type MyResource() =
    inherit Resources.BaseResource("http://my.cdn.net",
       "file1.js", "file2.js", "file3.css")
```

and you can place a `[<Require>]` attribute on the assembly to make the resource appear on every page on the site:

```ml
[<assembly: Require(typeof<MyResource>)>]
do ()
```

The documentation goes on to say that the attribute can be placed on modules, types and (module level) let bindings and WebSharper will build a dependency graph to figure out if a given page (Action) needs the dependency or not. I've tried a few things (using a Twitter Bootstrap resource declaration), but the only way I've gotten to make this work is the assembly attribute.

Can someone give an example (or provide a link) of how to do properly use the `[<Require>]` attribute so that it gets added on one Action, but not another?

For reference, here's by Twitter Bootstrap resource declaration:

```ml
[<Require(typeof<JQuery.Resources.JQuery>)>]
[<Sealed>]    
type BootstrapResource() =
    inherit Resources.BaseResource("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/", 
                                   "css/bootstrap.min.css", "js/bootstrap.min.js")
```

(I get that the `[<Require]>` attribute here here makes it a dependency of the Bootstrap resource, although I think WebSharper includes JQuery anyways, which would make it redundant.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having `[<Require(typeof<JQuery.Resources.JQuery>)>]` is not redundant as it tells WebSharper to always include JQuery before the currently defined resource.

`Require` attribute on assembly level in a referenced dll will not automatically add the resource to the page returned for a specific Action, only if the assembly referenced from one of the `Web.Control` types used for the page. It works the same for a smaller scope: `[<Require(typeof<MyResource>)>]` on a module, function, or type.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2013, in which you can edit while debugging, but that wasn't working. When I stopped and restarted debugging, the attribute worked as expected. Ah well. :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the `Require` attribute. It makes sense now that you've explained it. :)